# Sharing data between master thread and slave thread in interrupt driven environment in C

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, interrupt, shared-data

I have the following:

```
f1()
{
    while(1)
    {
        call f(2) if hardware interrupt pin goes high
    }
}

f2()
{
    if( th() not started )
    {
        start thread th()
    }
    else
    {
        return thread th() status
    }
}

th()
{
    time-consuming operation
}
```

At the moment, I use the following to initiate a struct in f2():

```
static struct SharedData shared;
if( shared == NULL)
{
    initialize shared
}
```

Then I pass a pointer to **shared** to the thread. The thread then updates **shared** periodically. f2() will then know if th() has been started based on elements of **shared** and it will check the status of th() by reading from **shared**.

Let's assume one of the elements of **shared** is a mutex to provide thread safety. Is this a good solution? Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I have tested the code and it works. I just need some expert advice here.

Thanks,

Comment: ?? 'I have tested the code and it works'.  In every OS I've ever used, it is not possible to create threads from interrupt-handlers.  Usually, the only thing you can do in there is signal a semaphore and then exit the handler via the OS interrupt entry point to ensure that a scheduler run is made so that any thread waiting on the semaphore is made ready/running.

Comment: Oh - hang on - are you using a thread to poll some boolean that is set by the interrupt-handler?  If so, that is not remotely an efficient way of communicating between interrupt-handlers and a multithreading OS.  It defeats the major advantage of a preemptive, multitasking OS - good I/O performance.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I'm polling a boolean set by the interrupt-handler because I couldn't start a thread inside the handler as you mentioned in your first comment. What is the best way to do this? You've explained a solution in your first comment, is this the best way? Thanks.

Comment: It's the way it's usually done.  The handler thread waits on a semaphore at the top of a loop that processes the interrupt, maybe by calling your 'time-consuming operation'.  The interrupt-handler signals the semaphore and then calls/jumps/whatever to some 'ExitInterrupt(bool schedRequired)' OS entry.  That makes the handler thread ready/running 'immediately', (and possibly preempting another thread that was running before the interrupt).  There is no polling and no continual thread creation/termination.  Summary - it's a pile faster and much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `f2()` uses the same mutex in the `shared` structure to lock before reading the data that the thread `th` uses to modify the data, I don't see any issues.

If you have more than one thread calling `f2()`, you may want to use a read-write lock for reading and writing of the thread status of `th`. The mutex could still be used to serialize the thread creation check. You could also use a `pthread_rwlock_wrlock()` to serialize `th` creation, but the code is arguably less clear.

Using a mutex to serialize `th` creation in `f2()`:

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&shared.rwlock);
result = shared.th_status;
if (! shared.th_created) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared.mutex);
    if (! shared.th_created) {
        pthread_create(...);
        shrared.th_created = 1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_mutex);
}
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&shared.rwlock);
return result;
```

Using the read-write lock to serialize `th` creation in `f2()`:

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&shared.rwlock);
result = shared.th_status;
if (! shared.th_created) {
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&shared.rwlock);
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&shared.rwlock);
    if (! shared.th_created) {
        pthread_create(...);
        shrared.th_created = 1;
    }
}
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&shared.rwlock);
return result;
```